# Get data that is no more than an hour old in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to use the statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data.example 
WHERE TIMESTAMP(timeCollected) < DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), 60, 'MINUTE')
```

to get data from my bigquery data. It seems to return same set of result even when time is not within the range. `timeCollected` is of the format `2015-10-29 16:05:06`.

I'm trying to build a query that is meant to return is data that is not older than an hour. So data collected within the last hour should be returned, the rest should be ignored.

Comment: the range means "anything older than an hour into the future"... I believe this should always return every entry in your table, unless you collect data in the future

Comment: what the query  is mean to return is  anything younger than an hour into the future. If the data is older than an hour, it should just ignore it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The query you made means "return to me anything that has a collection time smaller than an hour in the future" which will literally mean your whole table. You want the following (from what I got through your comment, at least) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM data.example 
WHERE TIMESTAMP(timeCollected) > DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), -60, 'MINUTE')
```

This means that any timeCollected that is NOT greater than an hour ago will not be returned. I believe this is what you want.

Also, unless you need it, Select * is not ideal in BigQuery. Since the data is saved by column, you can save money by selecting only what you need down the line. I don't know your use case, so * may be warranted though

Comment: This seems to work well except that some time outside the time interval is also included.

Answer (score 15):

Using Standard SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE timestamp > TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -60 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get table data collected within the last hour:

```
SELECT * FROM [data.example@-3600000--1]
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators

Comment: Any way to do this in Standard SQL?

Comment: @JoshLaird - Standard SQL does not support range decorators as Legacy SQL does. Meantime it does support analogue of snapshot decorator - see [FOR SYSTEM TIME AS OF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#syntax)  - if more questions - please post new one and I will be happy to answer more :o)

Answer (score 1):

Using Standard SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE timestamp > **TIMESTAMP_SUB**(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
```