# How to get TIMESTAMP of 15 minutes ago using BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436494/get-data-that-is-no-more-than-an-hour-old-in-bigquery) but this doesn't run on standard SQL

I tried to do:

```
WHERE datew > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 5 DAY )
```

But this doesn't work. According to the docs `DATE_SUB` supports only

```
DAY
WEEK. Equivalent to 7 DAYs.
MONTH
QUARTER
YEAR
```

How can I get current `time stamp - 15 minutes` on standard SQL with BigQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [timestamp_sub()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_sub) function.

How to use it:

```
SELECT
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS now, 
TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AS ago_15_min
```

Results

[image]

Comment: Just for general knowledge... what If I want to subtract 1 day and 15 minutes?

Comment: One of those 2:


`TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS ago_1day_15_min,

TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 1455 MINUTE) AS ago_1day_15_min2`